# Parse an xml file to extract element values using lxml and XPath in python

Tags: python, xml, xpath, xml-parsing, lxml

I have this `xml` file and I want to extract the values associated with certain specific elements. More specifically what I want is when the element value is `Marks` then check if next element value is `Marks of Student`(They are towards the end of the in the sample xml I have shown below ). If it is then extract/print these two tags and next 3 tags(which would be Minimum,Maximum, and Mean values):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
 xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
 xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
 <DocumentProperties xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
  <Version>16.00</Version>
 </DocumentProperties>
 <OfficeDocumentSettings xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
  <AllowPNG/>
 </OfficeDocumentSettings>
 <ExcelWorkbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
  <WindowHeight>9888</WindowHeight>
  <WindowWidth>15360</WindowWidth>
  <WindowTopX>0</WindowTopX>
  <WindowTopY>0</WindowTopY>
  <ProtectStructure>False</ProtectStructure>
  <ProtectWindows>False</ProtectWindows>
 </ExcelWorkbook>
 <Styles>
  <Style ss:ID="Default" ss:Name="Normal">
   <Alignment ss:Vertical="Bottom"/>
   <Borders/>
   <Font ss:FontName="Calibri" x:Family="Swiss" ss:Size="11" ss:Color="#000000"/>
   <Interior/>
   <NumberFormat/>
   <Protection/>
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="m5479808">
   <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Center" ss:Vertical="Bottom" ss:WrapText="1"/>
   <Borders>
    <Border ss:Position="Bottom" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Left" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Right" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Top" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
   </Borders>
   <Font ss:FontName="Arial, Helvetica" ss:Size="9" ss:Color="#000000" ss:Bold="1"/>
   <Interior ss:Color="#FFFFFF" ss:Pattern="Solid"/>
   <NumberFormat/>
   <Protection/>
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="m5479828">
   <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Center" ss:Vertical="Bottom" ss:WrapText="1"/>
   <Borders>
    <Border ss:Position="Bottom" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Left" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Right" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Top" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
   </Borders>
   <Font ss:FontName="Arial, Helvetica" ss:Size="9" ss:Color="#000000" ss:Bold="1"/>
   <Interior ss:Color="#FFFFFF" ss:Pattern="Solid"/>
   <NumberFormat/>
   <Protection/>
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="s62">
   <Alignment ss:Vertical="Bottom"/>
   <Borders/>
   <Font ss:FontName="Calibri" x:Family="Swiss" ss:Size="11" ss:Color="#000000"/>
   <Interior ss:Color="#FFFFFF" ss:Pattern="Solid"/>
   <NumberFormat/>
   <Protection/>
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="s64">
   <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Center" ss:Vertical="Bottom" ss:WrapText="1"/>
   <Borders/>
   <Font ss:FontName="Arial, Helvetica" ss:Size="12" ss:Color="#000000" ss:Bold="1"/>
   <Interior ss:Color="#FFFFFF" ss:Pattern="Solid"/>
   <NumberFormat/>
   <Protection/>
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="s65">
   <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Center" ss:Vertical="Bottom" ss:WrapText="1"/>
   <Borders>
    <Border ss:Position="Bottom" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Left" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Right" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Top" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
   </Borders>
   <Font ss:FontName="Arial, Helvetica" ss:Size="9" ss:Color="#000000" ss:Bold="1"/>
   <Interior ss:Color="#FFFFFF" ss:Pattern="Solid"/>
   <NumberFormat/>
   <Protection/>
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="s72">
   <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Right" ss:Vertical="Bottom" ss:WrapText="1"/>
   <Borders>
    <Border ss:Position="Bottom" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Left" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Right" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Top" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
   </Borders>
   <Font ss:FontName="Arial, Helvetica" ss:Size="9" ss:Color="#000000"/>
   <Interior/>
   <NumberFormat/>
   <Protection/>
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="s73">
   <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Left" ss:Vertical="Bottom" ss:WrapText="1"/>
   <Borders>
    <Border ss:Position="Bottom" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Left" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Right" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Top" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
   </Borders>
   <Font ss:FontName="Arial, Helvetica" ss:Size="9" ss:Color="#000000"/>
   <Interior/>
   <NumberFormat/>
   <Protection/>
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="s74">
   <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Center" ss:Vertical="Bottom" ss:WrapText="1"/>
   <Borders>
    <Border ss:Position="Bottom" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Left" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Right" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Top" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
   </Borders>
   <Font ss:FontName="Arial, Helvetica" ss:Size="9" ss:Color="#000000"/>
   <Interior/>
   <NumberFormat/>
   <Protection/>
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="s76">
   <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Center" ss:Vertical="Bottom" ss:WrapText="1"/>
   <Borders/>
   <Font ss:FontName="Arial, Helvetica" ss:Size="9" ss:Color="#000000"/>
   <Interior ss:Color="#FFFFFF" ss:Pattern="Solid"/>
   <NumberFormat/>
   <Protection/>
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="s78">
   <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Center" ss:Vertical="Bottom" ss:WrapText="1"/>
   <Borders/>
   <Font ss:FontName="Arial, Helvetica" ss:Size="9" ss:Color="#000000" ss:Bold="1"/>
   <Interior/>
   <NumberFormat/>
   <Protection/>
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="s79">
   <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Center" ss:Vertical="Bottom" ss:WrapText="1"/>
   <Borders>
    <Border ss:Position="Bottom" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Left" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Right" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Top" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
   </Borders>
   <Font ss:FontName="Arial, Helvetica" ss:Size="9" ss:Color="#000000" ss:Bold="1"/>
   <Interior ss:Color="#FFFFFF" ss:Pattern="Solid"/>
   <NumberFormat ss:Format="###0"/>
   <Protection/>
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="s80">
   <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Center" ss:Vertical="Bottom" ss:WrapText="1"/>
   <Borders>
    <Border ss:Position="Bottom" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Left" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Right" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Top" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
   </Borders>
   <Font ss:FontName="Arial, Helvetica" ss:Size="9" ss:Color="#000000" ss:Bold="1"/>
   <Interior ss:Color="#FFFFFF" ss:Pattern="Solid"/>
   <NumberFormat ss:Format="###0.00"/>
   <Protection/>
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="s81">
   <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Center" ss:Vertical="Bottom" ss:WrapText="1"/>
   <Borders>
    <Border ss:Position="Bottom" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Left" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Right" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Top" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
   </Borders>
   <Font ss:FontName="Arial, Helvetica" ss:Size="9" ss:Color="#000000" ss:Bold="1"/>
   <Interior ss:Color="#FFFFFF" ss:Pattern="Solid"/>
   <NumberFormat ss:Format="#,##0"/>
   <Protection/>
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="s82">
   <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Right" ss:Vertical="Bottom" ss:WrapText="1"/>
   <Borders>
    <Border ss:Position="Bottom" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Left" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Right" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Top" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
   </Borders>
   <Font ss:FontName="Arial, Helvetica" ss:Size="9" ss:Color="#000000"/>
   <Interior/>
   <NumberFormat ss:Format="###0"/>
   <Protection/>
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="s83">
   <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Right" ss:Vertical="Bottom" ss:WrapText="1"/>
   <Borders>
    <Border ss:Position="Bottom" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Left" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Right" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Top" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
   </Borders>
   <Font ss:FontName="Arial, Helvetica" ss:Size="9" ss:Color="#000000"/>
   <Interior/>
   <NumberFormat ss:Format="###0.00"/>
   <Protection/>
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="s84">
   <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Right" ss:Vertical="Bottom" ss:WrapText="1"/>
   <Borders>
    <Border ss:Position="Bottom" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Left" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Right" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Top" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
   </Borders>
   <Font ss:FontName="Arial, Helvetica" ss:Size="9" ss:Color="#000000"/>
   <Interior/>
   <NumberFormat ss:Format="#,##0"/>
   <Protection/>
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="s85">
   <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Center" ss:Vertical="Bottom" ss:WrapText="1"/>
   <Borders>
    <Border ss:Position="Bottom" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Left" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Right" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Top" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
   </Borders>
   <Font ss:FontName="Arial, Helvetica" ss:Size="9" ss:Color="#000000" ss:Bold="1"/>
   <Interior ss:Color="#FFFFFF" ss:Pattern="Solid"/>
   <NumberFormat ss:Format="##,##0"/>
   <Protection/>
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="s86">
   <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Center" ss:Vertical="Bottom" ss:WrapText="1"/>
   <Borders>
    <Border ss:Position="Bottom" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Left" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Right" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Top" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
   </Borders>
   <Font ss:FontName="Arial, Helvetica" ss:Size="9" ss:Color="#000000" ss:Bold="1"/>
   <Interior ss:Color="#FFFFFF" ss:Pattern="Solid"/>
   <NumberFormat ss:Format="####0.00"/>
   <Protection/>
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="s87">
   <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Right" ss:Vertical="Bottom" ss:WrapText="1"/>
   <Borders>
    <Border ss:Position="Bottom" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Left" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Right" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Top" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
   </Borders>
   <Font ss:FontName="Arial, Helvetica" ss:Size="9" ss:Color="#000000"/>
   <Interior/>
   <NumberFormat ss:Format="##,##0"/>
   <Protection/>
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="s88">
   <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Right" ss:Vertical="Bottom" ss:WrapText="1"/>
   <Borders>
    <Border ss:Position="Bottom" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Left" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Right" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Top" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
   </Borders>
   <Font ss:FontName="Arial, Helvetica" ss:Size="9" ss:Color="#000000"/>
   <Interior/>
   <NumberFormat ss:Format="####0.00"/>
   <Protection/>
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="s89">
   <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Center" ss:Vertical="Bottom" ss:WrapText="1"/>
   <Borders>
    <Border ss:Position="Bottom" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Left" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Right" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Top" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
   </Borders>
   <Font ss:FontName="Arial, Helvetica" ss:Size="9" ss:Color="#000000" ss:Bold="1"/>
   <Interior ss:Color="#FFFFFF" ss:Pattern="Solid"/>
   <NumberFormat ss:Format="@"/>
   <Protection/>
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="s90">
   <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Left" ss:Vertical="Bottom" ss:WrapText="1"/>
   <Borders>
    <Border ss:Position="Bottom" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Left" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Right" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Top" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
   </Borders>
   <Font ss:FontName="Arial, Helvetica" ss:Size="9" ss:Color="#000000"/>
   <Interior/>
   <NumberFormat ss:Format="@"/>
   <Protection/>
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="s91">
   <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Center" ss:Vertical="Bottom" ss:WrapText="1"/>
   <Borders>
    <Border ss:Position="Bottom" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Left" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Right" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Top" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
   </Borders>
   <Font ss:FontName="Arial, Helvetica" ss:Size="9" ss:Color="#000000"/>
   <Interior/>
   <NumberFormat ss:Format="@"/>
   <Protection/>
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="s92">
   <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Left" ss:Vertical="Bottom"/>
   <Borders/>
   <Font ss:FontName="Arial, Helvetica" ss:Size="12" ss:Color="#000000" ss:Bold="1"/>
   <Interior ss:Color="#FFFFFF" ss:Pattern="Solid"/>
   <NumberFormat/>
   <Protection/>
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="s98">
   <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Center" ss:Vertical="Bottom"/>
   <Borders/>
   <Font ss:FontName="Arial, Helvetica" ss:Size="12" ss:Color="#000000" ss:Bold="1"/>
   <Interior ss:Color="#FFFFFF" ss:Pattern="Solid"/>
   <NumberFormat/>
   <Protection/>
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="s99">
   <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Right" ss:Vertical="Bottom"/>
   <Borders>
    <Border ss:Position="Bottom" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Left" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Right" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Top" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
   </Borders>
   <Font ss:FontName="Arial, Helvetica" ss:Size="9" ss:Color="#000000" ss:Bold="1"/>
   <Interior ss:Color="#FFFFFF" ss:Pattern="Solid"/>
   <NumberFormat/>
   <Protection/>
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="s100">
   <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Left" ss:Vertical="Bottom"/>
   <Borders>
    <Border ss:Position="Bottom" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Left" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Right" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Top" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
   </Borders>
   <Font ss:FontName="Arial, Helvetica" ss:Size="9" ss:Color="#000000" ss:Bold="1"/>
   <Interior ss:Color="#FFFFFF" ss:Pattern="Solid"/>
   <NumberFormat ss:Format="@"/>
   <Protection/>
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="s101">
   <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Left" ss:Vertical="Bottom"/>
   <Borders>
    <Border ss:Position="Bottom" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Left" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Right" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Top" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
   </Borders>
   <Font ss:FontName="Arial, Helvetica" ss:Size="9" ss:Color="#000000" ss:Bold="1"/>
   <Interior ss:Color="#FFFFFF" ss:Pattern="Solid"/>
   <NumberFormat/>
   <Protection/>
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="s102">
   <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Right" ss:Vertical="Bottom"/>
   <Borders>
    <Border ss:Position="Bottom" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Left" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Right" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Top" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
   </Borders>
   <Font ss:FontName="Arial, Helvetica" ss:Size="9" ss:Color="#000000" ss:Bold="1"/>
   <Interior ss:Color="#FFFFFF" ss:Pattern="Solid"/>
   <NumberFormat ss:Format="@"/>
   <Protection/>
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="s103">
   <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Right" ss:Vertical="Bottom"/>
   <Borders>
    <Border ss:Position="Bottom" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Left" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Right" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Top" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
   </Borders>
   <Font ss:FontName="Arial, Helvetica" ss:Size="9" ss:Color="#000000"/>
   <Interior/>
   <NumberFormat/>
   <Protection/>
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="s104">
   <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Left" ss:Vertical="Bottom"/>
   <Borders>
    <Border ss:Position="Bottom" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Left" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Right" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Top" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
   </Borders>
   <Font ss:FontName="Arial, Helvetica" ss:Size="9" ss:Color="#000000"/>
   <Interior/>
   <NumberFormat ss:Format="@"/>
   <Protection/>
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="s105">
   <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Left" ss:Vertical="Bottom"/>
   <Borders>
    <Border ss:Position="Bottom" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Left" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Right" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Top" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
   </Borders>
   <Font ss:FontName="Arial, Helvetica" ss:Size="9" ss:Color="#000000"/>
   <Interior/>
   <NumberFormat/>
   <Protection/>
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="s106">
   <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Right" ss:Vertical="Bottom"/>
   <Borders>
    <Border ss:Position="Bottom" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Left" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Right" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Top" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
   </Borders>
   <Font ss:FontName="Arial, Helvetica" ss:Size="9" ss:Color="#000000"/>
   <Interior/>
   <NumberFormat ss:Format="@"/>
   <Protection/>
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="s108">
   <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Left" ss:Vertical="Bottom"/>
   <Borders/>
   <Font ss:FontName="Arial, Helvetica" ss:Size="9" ss:Color="#000000"/>
   <Interior ss:Color="#FFFFFF" ss:Pattern="Solid"/>
   <NumberFormat/>
   <Protection/>
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="s109">
   <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Left" ss:Vertical="Bottom"/>
   <Borders/>
   <Font ss:FontName="Calibri" x:Family="Swiss" ss:Size="11" ss:Color="#000000"/>
   <Interior ss:Color="#FFFFFF" ss:Pattern="Solid"/>
   <NumberFormat/>
   <Protection/>
  </Style>
 </Styles>
 <Worksheet ss:Name="Dataset Contents">
  <Table ss:ExpandedColumnCount="6" ss:ExpandedRowCount="86" x:FullColumns="1"
   x:FullRows="1" ss:StyleID="s62" ss:DefaultRowHeight="14.4">
   <Column ss:StyleID="s62" ss:Width="33.6"/>
   <Column ss:StyleID="s62" ss:Width="108"/>
   <Column ss:StyleID="s62" ss:Width="67.8" ss:Span="1"/>
   <Column ss:Index="5" ss:StyleID="s62" ss:Width="94.8"/>
   <Column ss:StyleID="s62" ss:Width="229.8"/>
   <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0" ss:Height="31.95">
    <Cell ss:MergeAcross="5" ss:StyleID="s64"><Data ss:Type="String">Students Score Summary</Data></Cell>
   </Row>

  <!--...bunch of <Row><Cell><Data> tags which I don't want to extract..-->

  <Cell ss:StyleID="s65"><Data ss:Type="String">Variable Name</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s65"><Data ss:Type="String">Variable Label</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s79"><Data ss:Type="String">Minimum&#10;Value</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s79"><Data ss:Type="String">Maximum&#10;Value</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s80"><Data ss:Type="String">Mean&#10;Value</Data></Cell>

   <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0" ss:Height="15">
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s73"><Data ss:Type="String">Marks</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s73"><Data ss:Type="String">Marks of Student</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s82"><Data ss:Type="Number">0</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s82"><Data ss:Type="Number">96</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s83"><Data ss:Type="Number">65.71</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0" ss:Height="15">
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s73"><Data ss:Type="String">Name</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s73"><Data ss:Type="String">Name of Students</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s82"><Data ss:Type="Number">n/a</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s82"><Data ss:Type="Number">n/a</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s83"><Data ss:Type="Number">n/a</Data></Cell>
   </Row>

   <!--...bunch of <Row><Cell><Data> tags which I don't want to extract..-->
    .
    .
    .
</Workbook>
```

Currently I have this code where I am using `ElementTree` as to parse the xml file but it is not producing any output(it doesn't print anything).

```
import io

import xml.etree.ElementTree

tree = xml.etree.ElementTree.parse('xmlFile1.xml').getroot()

parent_map = {c: p for p in tree.getiterator() for c in p}

def search_data(first_text, next_text):
    data_with_marks = [data_node
                       for data_node in tree.findall(".//Data")
                       if data_node.text == first_text]
    for marks_elem in data_with_marks:
        cell_elem = parent_map[marks_elem]
        row_elem = parent_map[cell_elem]
        cell_nodes = list(row_elem)
        curr_index = cell_nodes.index(cell_elem)
        next_index = curr_index + 1
        next_data_node = next(iter(cell_nodes[next_index]))
        if next_data_node.text == next_text:
            return [next(iter(cell_node))
                    for cell_node in cell_nodes[curr_index:curr_index + 6]]
    return []

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for node in search_data("Marks", "Marks of Student"):
        print(node.text)
```

I am trying to look for `lxml` and `XPath` but don't know how to do that. How can I modify my current code to use `lxml` and `XPath` to parse the `xml` file and get the output I want?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to extract the wanted information with ElementTree:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

NSMAP = {"ss": "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"}

tree = ET.parse("xmlFile1.xml")

# Find all Row elements
rows = tree.findall(".//ss:Row", NSMAP)

# For each Row, get all Data 'grandchildren'
for row in rows:
    data = row.findall("ss:Cell/ss:Data", NSMAP)

    if data and len(data) == 5:     
        # If first two Data elements are what we want, print out all Data element values
        if data[0].text == "Marks" and data[1].text == "Marks of Student":
            for d in data:
                print (d.text)
```

Output:

```
Marks
Marks of Student
0
96
65.71
```

The default namespace is `urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet`, and the elements you are interested in are in this namespace. That's why we need to use the `NSMAP` dictionary. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#parsing-xml-with-namespaces.

Comment: I am getting `IndexError: list index out of range` at `if data[0].text == "Marks" and data[1].text == "Marks of Student":`

Comment: There is no error checking in the code. If there are Rows with no Cell/Data children, for example, that will trigger an error. I suppose that your actual XML is more complicated than the one in the question. My main point was that you must take namespaces into account.

Comment: Ok. How can I check/remove Rows with no Cell/Data?

Comment: The code works with lxml too btw (just change the `import` statement to `from lxml import etree as ET`).